# Why does nested INDEX(IF) not find matching value?

Tags: excel

I need to SUM about matching array values in two dimensions, eventually requiring an array formula. As first step I've tried to implement the match in a single dimension, i.e. return `B` column when `A` value matches:

[image: sheet]

What I'm seeing is that the match only ever works for the first cell. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Because only the first formula will have an array returned where the first hit was `TRUE`. The other two formulas will have array returned where the first value in the array will evaluate to `-1`. You are looking for an actual `MATCH` function here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MATCH:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$B$3,MATCH(A5,$A$1:$A$3,0))
```